# Is it all com.android.support libraries and SDK version must be equal, higher, or lower?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

If you look at my 2 libraries which is (support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1 and support:design:25.3.1) its in a red line and it says "This library should not use a different version (25) than the compileSDKVersion(24). Should I change my SDK into higher version or change my support libraries lower than SDK or higher than SDK?

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    lintOptions{
        abortOnError false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sangabriel.myrealapp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
         release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     }
}

dependencies {

    // Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
         exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Design library for Coordinator Layout and Toolbars
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Comment: The error pretty much tells you what to do. Better stop searching problems where the solution is simple ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes when you use any google or core libraries all of its version should be same.

> In your case you can do two things. **Your `compileSdkVersion` is `24` So that you can use either of these two things**
>
> 1. You can change all your library/dependancy version to `24.2.1` as `compileSdkVersion`
> 2. You can change all your library/dependancy version to `25.3.1` to newer version

**Example**

1.Case one

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
```

2.Case two

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Comment: I follow the case one but why my appcompat is stil in a red line?

Comment: And if I want to update my compileSDKversion, what should i do? Advance thank you. I am just a beginner in android I just need some information. Thank you!

Comment: @RaemarcSanGabriel There are multiple ways you can achieve this. The simple method is that you can directly change the 24 to 25 and resync the project it will download the new dependencies and everything. But best thing is that follow this step. Choose menu item File->Project Structure, and click your modules (like MyApp), and you will find "Compile Sdk Version" in Properties tab.

Comment: Already done. All fine now, thank your for answering my problem! Just currently facing my new problem about FirebaseAuthCredentialsException: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password. Any info about this? Thank you!

Comment: Add a new question in SO. along with the question please mention your stacktrace. It will help to identify the problem.Also mention the question in this comment. @RaemarcSanGabriel.

Answer (score 0):

```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
```

libraries and SDK version must me same.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question hehe. Just a beginner need more info to learn. :)

Answer (score 0):

As your whole android project stay in 24 version. My openion is make the design dependnacy lower:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
```

And if you want to keep up to date then you also can do this.

Comment: Thank you. Everything is making sense to me now hehe